# Constrained Optimization- Value is not in the interior of the feasible region

Tags: r, optimization, error-handling, minimization

I'm trying to replicate the Excel Solver in R- which is basically a constraint optimization problem

I'm trying to minimize the cost per action which is total spend/ total actions which equals to the below function with a few constraints.

CPA function:

```
(a+b+c+d)/((consta+(Ba*ln(a)))+ (constb+(Bb*ln(b)))+(constc+(Bc*ln(c)))+(constd+(Bd*ln(d)))
```

where the unknown variables are a,b,c,d and const* stands for constant from a regressions and B* stand for coefficient from a regression (so they are values that I have).

Here is the simplified filled in function that I'm trying to minimize:

```
(a+b+c+d)/ (((69.31*ln(a))+(14.885*ln(b))+(21.089*ln(c))+(9.934*ln(d))-(852.93))
```

Constraints:

```
a+b+c+d>=0    
a+b+c+d<=130000(total spend)
a<=119000 (maxa)
a>=272.56(mina)
b<=11000(maxb)
b>=2.04(minb)
c<=2900(maxc)
c>=408.16(minc)
d<=136800(maxd)
d>=55.02(mind)
```

I'm doing this using the constraints optimization function. My code is below:

```
g<-function(a,b,c,d) { (a+b+c+d)/((consta+(Ba*log(a)))+ (constb+(Bb*log(b)))+ (constc+(Bc*log(c)))+ (constd+(Bd*log(d)))) }

gr<-function(a,b,c,d) {

c((1/((consta+(Ba*log(a)))+ (constb+(Bb*log(b)))+(constc+(Bc*log(c)))+  (constd+(Bd*log(d)))))-((Ba*(a+b+c+d))/(a*((consta+(Ba*log(a)))+ (constb+(Bb*log(b)))+(constc+(Bc*log(c)))+(constd+(Bd*log(d))))**2)),

(1/((consta+(Ba*log(a)))+ (constb+(Bb*log(b)))+(constc+(Bc*log(c)))+   (constd+(Bd*log(d)))))-((Bb*(a+b+c+d))/(b*((consta+(Ba*log(a)))+ (constb+(Bb*log(b)))+(constc+(Bc*log(c)))+(constd+(Bd*log(d))))**2)),

(1/((consta+(Ba*log(a)))+ (constb+(Bb*log(b)))+(constc+(Bc*log(c)))+(constd+(Bd*log(d)))))-((Bc*(a+b+c+d))/(c*((consta+(Ba*log(a)))+ (constb+(Bb*log(b)))+(constc+(Bc*log(c)))+(constd+(Bd*log(d))))**2)),

(1/((consta+(Ba*log(a)))+ (constb+(Bb*log(b)))+(constc+(Bc*log(c)))+(constd+(Bd*log(d)))))-((Bd*(a+b+c+d))/(d*((consta+(Ba*log(a)))+ (constb+(Bb*log(b)))+(constc+(Bc*log(c)))+(constd+(Bd*log(d))))**2)))

}

A<-matrix(c(1,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1),10,4)

B<- c(mina, -maxa, minb, -maxb, minc, -maxc, mind, -maxd,-totalspend, 0)

constrOptim(c(273,6,409,56),gr,NULL,A,B)'
```

When I run the optimization function, it states that the values are not in the interior of the feasible region(`Error in constrOptim(c(273, 6, 409, 56), gr, NULL, A, B) : initial value is not in the interior of the feasible region)`. However, the starting values that I have inputted satisfy all of the function constraints. I also checked to make sure that my function, gradient function, Ui, and Ci are properly coded. Any help is appreciated.